# Why not just use all String type in Java and convert as needed?

Tags: java, types, casting, theory

I'm playing devils advocate here,  but if casting is so easy and not able to be disallowed why not just use all string types in Java and just cast to a number right before the math operation.

Casting seems to sort of defeat the purpose of a Strongly typed language.

What advantages/point are there to actually using primitive numeric types?

edit: sorry for calling it casting, I was under the impression that casting was a general term for coverting between types, I see now it's for primitive types and parsing is what happens when converting a string. TIL!!

Comment: Performance, for one.

Comment: What advantages/point are there to always use string?

Comment: I don't think you mean casting. And even if that made sense, because why on earth would you want to incur (a) the overhead, (b) the lack of readability, and (c) the handling of the different numeric types?

Comment: You cannot cast String to a number, you need to parse it. And parsing is slow. Also why would you hide a number as a String? What advantages are there besides confusion?

Comment: how do you cast a string to an int?

Comment: Also why is this downvoted? It looks like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: @m0skit0: Is it?  It's as valid as "why don't we always store values in an arraylist of bits?".

Comment: Although it isn't exactly a programming question, it still relates to elements of programming.  I find it a valid question...although a more obvious one if you just researched a bit

Comment: @m0skit0 In what way? Obvious answer is obvious.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what's the problem with "why don't we always store values in an arraylist of bits?".

Comment: @DaveNewton obvious for you, not for OP.

Comment: @m0skit0 Because that would be just as ridiculous. (Well, probably more so, but still O(N).)

Comment: @m0skit0: IMHO, there'd need to be some kind of premise for why the question is being asked.  So answering Zong's counter-question (comments above) should be a prerequisite to posing this kind of question.  Otherwise it's just "Why don't we do this wacky thing?"

Comment: @m0skit0 I seriously doubt it's not obvious for the OP, either.

Comment: It's not so much obvious as it is uninformed: OP is not describing casting, but rather parsing. You can't cast a `String` to anything, particularly not anything numeric. It must be parsed, a completely different process from casting which, as other comments have stated, is slow and expensive.

Comment: "Not providing any guaranteed semblance of safety". `Integer.parseInt("3")` is not exactly easy to accidentally type out. And "butthurt"? C'mon.

Comment: Yes but what is the purpose of declaring anything other than a String? Or having function parameters anything other than strings?

Java will function as a dynamically typed language at that point.


Then you can just parse to a primitive type as needed, int or double  or whatever.


Is performance the only reason?

Comment: If you always use a string java is functioning as a dynamically typed language at that point, like js, python, or all the others.

(keep in mind I'm playing devils advocate, I know it's wrong to do)

Comment: @Nickthemagicman Performance is rarely the main issue. The main issue is readability, clarity and maintenance.  Even most dynamic language doesn't think its a good idea to use String for every type.

Comment: @Nickthemagicman That still wouldn't be dynamically typed. The reason static type checking exists is to prevent a large class of simple errors. Without it, you have all of the ceremonial overhead of Java with zero of the advantages, giving you the absolute worst of both worlds. It's why most Java web frameworks provide a layer of conversion between HTTP's string parameters and something actually valuable within the Java ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's make sure you understand what **parsing** and **casting** is:

> Parsing and casting are two entirely different beasts. Parsing is
>   (normally) the process of analyzing a String and checking whether or
>   not it obeys certain grammar rules, e.g. your Java source code is
>   parsed for syntax errors.
>
> Casting primitive types (ints, longs, doubles) is converting one type
>   to another type according to certain rules. Parsing object types is
>   'viewing' an object as another type, e.g. a String also is an Object
>   and it also implements the interface Comparable. You can
>   view/cast a String to all the other types.

Source:  http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/35811-parsing-vs-casting.html

You cannot cast a String to int:

```
String line = "7";   
int a  = (int)line;// This doesnt work, you'll get an error
```

However, you can parse it:

```
String line = "7";  
int a = Integer.parseInt(line);//This is a perfectly acceptable statement in java
```

Source:  http://www.coderanch.com/t/439266/java/java/Casting-Parsing

Now, the reason why we don't standardize Strings as our primitive data type is for a a handful of reasons:

- Inefficient to parse
- Easier to compile into machine/assembly language if variables are purely primitive data types (double, int, boolean).
- If we used "0" instead of 0, then the program would have to take an extra step to realize the String is the value zero where as it could easily grab it from the registry.

Comment: THANKS! I meant parsing !!! My mistake. I overgeneralized casting to think it was just conversion of one type to another!
I see now that it's just primitive conversions.

Comment: Generally you want to convert between String to int once (at the beginning), then process with the ints.  Then convert int back to String when outputting data.  Of course, this completely depends on what you are doing.  I'm just describing the most generic simple process.

Comment: Why not make all parameters of functions strings and convert inside if needed? 

This makes the function much more general. 

I know it's wrong but I'm just trying to understand why.

It's basically because 'parsing' is performance intensive?

Comment: Strings are expensive to represent due to the language having to work with OS to process that.  Boolean can be easily represented (0 and 1).  ints and doubles can "easily" (easy for a computer lol) be represented by binary.  Strings are far more complex to represent so it takes more power and time

Comment: I see.  So the advantage to not using all strings and making java a more or less dynamically typed language is performance. 

That's what I was wondering. Thanks!

Comment: Well there's literally no typing in so many other languages and it seems to work fine. 

You could argue that using types in general: "is verbose, inconvenient, error prone, and not at all the most common use case".

What is typing providing us to make it worth the hassle when it's so easy to get around?

Performance is the only reason I can understand.


I'm not trying to be a jerk just trying to be scientific about the usage of types:)

This seems to be the best answer to this question I've found and still isn't 100%.

http://blog.jessitron.com/2012/03/strong-typing-in-java-religious.html

Comment: Cool. I guess this is a bit of a static vs dynamic type argument.  It just seems to me that if you declare a variable in a statically typed language it just simply shouldn't be parsed or cast in any way throughout its lifetime just based on priniciple. 

I.e. parsing shouldn't even be allowed.

Comment: What @ZongZhengLi is saying is correct.  I'd recommend reading more about the JVM and assembly languages.  Here's a super small introduction:  http://voices.yahoo.com/introduction-java-virtual-machine-jvm-java-2333424.html

Comment: @Nickthemagicman You may *want* to convert between Java types for perfectly valid reasons, e.g., converting to a string value for output or serialization. Casting lets you do math on disparate numeric types, for example. This isn't a static vs. dynamic typing argument at all.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, ya'll. As a dynamic language type of guy the urge is there to just use everything in Java as strings and just parse as needed to get my dynamic fix but I'm fully aware of how wrong that is.  
I think the ultimate solution for type purity is just to make a class out of everything and use the more primitive types to build up the class like in this article.

http://blog.jessitron.com/2012/03/strong-typing-in-java-religious.html